# How to put gwt panels and widgets in CellList?

Tags: gwt, celllist

I want to put a complex layout with text-fields and operation buttons for each cell in a CellList.  So I want to put a GWT panel to organize the widgets.

Is it possible to put gwt panels and widgets in CellList? I tried to extend AbstractCell and override render(). But seems only HTML can be rendered. I didn't find a way to render normal gwt panels and widgets. 
CompositeCell seems going through List> automatically, you can not arrange widget as you wish. Also, I don't know whether normal widgets like PushButton can be used in CompositedCell.

Please give me a sample if you tried this before? Thanks a lot.

Comment: CompositeCell seems going through List < HasCell < ContactInfo, ? > >  automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to put GWT widgets or Panels in a `CellWidgets`.
`CellWidgets` are designed for rapid rendering of large amounts of data.
If you don't have that use case you can still use a [FlexTable](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html).
Otherwise you have to create a `CompositeCell` or `AbstractCell` and implement the `render` and event handling methods yourself.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I started to use CompositeCell and AbstractCell. Seems CompositeCell can't work as expected yet in 2.5rc1.